# convert string to date format error

Tags: java, string, date

I want to convert string to date but the out output date differ from the input date

```
  String  dateString="04/01/2014";
  SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
  try {
Date date=format.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(date);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output is Sun Dec 29 00:00:00 EET 2013

Comment: That is the correct output. What are you expecting and why? Read the javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Change `DD` by `dd` and `YYYY` by `yyyy`.

Comment: this is a correct output! You are outputting the date not the string! If you want to output the date object you have to apply the formatter on that object

Comment: input is 04/01/2014 but output is 12/29/2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string is wrong, from [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) -

> D     Day in year     Number  189
>
> d     Day in month    Number  10

and

> y     Year    Year    1996; 96
>
> Y     Week year   Year    2009; 09

So, you wanted -

```
String  dateString="04/01/2014";
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
try {
  Date date=format.parse(dateString);
  System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```